# How to install without make?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I am working with a BeagleBoard and I have already compiled ZMQ library with arm-linux-gnueabi gcc compiler. The problem is I don't know where to copy all that files because I don't have make command nor I am able to install it.

If I run:

```
uname -mrs
```

I get:

```
Linux 3.2.8-mg01.3 armv7l
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't have `make`, how were you able to build `libzmq` then?

Comment: I used another machine to cross compile it for arm.

Answer (score 2):

Build & install required library on your build machine:

```
./configure --prefix=/custom/location
make && make install
```

And then just copy `/custom/location` from your build machine to the target machine's root `/`.
You need to check that no stuff are being overwritten (or at least that no dependencies got lost).

Another, correct way, would be to create an installable package (i.e., `deb` or `rpm`), but that is a different question.

Comment: The `cp` would be easier if you *tar.gz* before hand.

Comment: It depends on your environment. Often during development I just mount the file system of other device via NFS. :-)